# setFullScreenIntent does not work second time

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, android-notifications

I have an application in android and I want to bring an activity to foreground in some cases. I use NotificationManager for this. Here is my code. The problem is, activity is brought to front successfully at first time, but then it does not. Also, this code is run from service.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                        .setContentTitle("Bring me front!")
                        .setContentText("Bring me!!! BRING!!!")
                        .setFullScreenIntent(contentIntent, true);

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things to check:

1. Your intent will probably need [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) (and possibly [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)) to ensure that the activity is brought to the front.
2. Be sure you're not trying to reuse the same PendingIntent more than once; each time you post this Notification you'll need to construct a new PendingIntent for use with `fullScreenIntent`.

Comment: Thanks, I've already solved this issue and flags you mentioned where used in solution:

Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    intent.setClassName("co.simplytech.bulova_time", "co.simplytech.bulova_time.MainActivity");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);

Comment: None of proposed solutions work for me. I didn't have any errors, it still a normal notification.

Answer (score 6):

The NotificationManager has the (undocumented) behavior that it will *ignore* the fullScreenIntent field if you post a new Notification that matches the ID of one that's already active.

Comment: That's exactly the issue we've been experiencing - although only on **some devices**, not on all of them.

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work on Android 13.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. In my case I missed two things:

1. USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT permission in Manifest.
2. A password or graphic pattern must be set on your phone settings. UI must be NOT available to the user immediately after you press the unlock button. Then fullscreen activity shows.